# List not writing into a CSV file properly

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a `list` like:

```
('so glad', 'happy')
('it is so sad', 'sad')
```

I want to write this lists into a CSV file like :

```
column1          column2
so glad          happy
it is so sad     sad
```

I used following code to do this:

```
with open('test.csv', "a") as outfile:
    for entries in my_list:
        outfile.write(entries)
        outfile.write("\n")
```

But it writes into the CSV file as

```
column1
so glad
happy
it is so sad
sad
```

How can I make this code do as I expected?

Comment: You never define `my_list`, and your indentation is invalid. Please correct your example.

Comment: How does your `my_list` look like?

Comment: You do not have any lists in you code. `('so glad', 'happy')` is not a list. It is a tuple.

Comment: my list= ('so glad', 'happy'),('it is so sad', 'sad')

Comment: @ChathurikaJayawardana, this is not a list. This is a tuple of tuples. I think, you need to study a bit deeper about python datatypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For python 3:
Use **writerow** to write a row taken from a list(iterable)

```
import csv
my_list =[('so glad', 'happy'),
('it is so sad', 'sad')]
with open('mycsv.csv','w+') as fileobj:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(fileobj)
    for row in my_list:
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

or Use **writerows** which takes an iterable (an iterable is anything that can be used to iterate so your `my_list` is an list iterable) and takes rows and saves them accordingly

```
import csv
my_list =[('so so glad', 'happy'),
('it is so sad', 'sad')]
with open('mycsv.csv','w+') as fileobj:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(fileobj)
    csvwriter.writerows(my_list)
```

For python 2:

`with open('mycsv.csv','w+') as fileobj:`

use wb instead of w+

The output in `mycsv.csv` is:

```
so so glad,happy
it is so sad,sad
```

Also note i used **w+** as mode here which truncates that is empties the csv file if already exists or creates a new one and writes content to them

There are several modes to write use one for your need.
Take a look at the [File modes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) documentation for python

> On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. Python on Windows makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that in JPEG or EXE files.

Comment: According to your code the output is s,o, ,g,l,a,d

h,a,p,p,y

i,t, ,i,s, ,g,o,o,d

h,a,p,p,y

Comment: It separated each words by ','

Comment: The `csv` module has some very specific requirements regarding how the file is opened depending on the version of Python. Python 2 needs the binary flag so the file should be opened `open('fname.csv', 'wb')`. Python 3 is like this `open('fanned.csv', 'w', newline='')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    wr = csv.writer(outfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(entries)
```

Comment: Your code make a unlimited loop. How can I avoid this.

Comment: @ChathurikaJayawardana: The code should work fine provided you are using Python 2.7 and `entries = [('so glad', 'happy'), ('it is so sad', 'sad')]`. Why do you believe it makes an "unlimited loop"?

Comment: @Chathurika: There's no explicit loop in this code.